# Is it safe to yield a ndb.Future more than once?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Is it safe to do this?

```py
@ndb.tasklet
def foo():
    # Note that I do not yield right here
    future = some_key.get_async()

    # Perform some other code

    if some_condition:
        # I need the get_async result here
        entity = yield future

    # I also need the get_async result here.
    # If some_condition was true, I would be yielding this future
    # for the second time. Is this ok?
    entity = yield future
```

Please don't tell me that I could just `yield` at the top of the function and use `entity` in the rest of the code. My actual function is a little more elaborate than this, and I have a few conditional codepaths that may need to use `entity` and I want to `yield` at the latest moment possible to be able to perform my other code while the entity is being fetched in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's safe!

If you check the Future class in ndb, it will set result when done, and multiple yields or get_result will check if it's done and return the stored result.

google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py, line 324 in SDK 1.7.4

Comment: What if App Engine changes its implementation in the future? I'd feel more confident if this were documented. My guess is that this won't actually ever change; my point is that the current implementation is not a guarantee, and should not be relied upon.

Comment: According to docs, you can yield a future. Is the future still a future after yielding?